# Server 14.04 - How to make all files in folder with same permissions

Tags: permissions

Take a look:

[image]

I must change all files to have permissions `-rw-rw---- 1` for all files there. As you can see some of them are with `drwx------ 2`, these one must be changed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't change directories into files. What exactly is your goal?

Comment: Yo Iron-Man, you shouldn't change all the files permission which are of MySQL to whatver you want. And the d in the front indicates its a directory.

Answer (score 1):

go to directory in which you want to change permission then
use below command for files:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
```

it will change all file permission to 660

and for directory use :

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

it will change all directory permission to 755.

entry that start with `d` shows directory and entry strart with `-` shows file.
for example `drwx------` is directory.